# Adding a scrollbar in PHP/CSS

Tags: php, css

How would I add the scrollbar to the information outputted by the database:

IE:

```
DATA   S  /\
DATA   C  ||
DATA   R  ||
DATA   O  ||
DATA   L  ||
DATA   L  ||
DATA   B  ||
DATA   A  ||
DATA   R  \/
```

CODE:

```
<?php
   mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass") or die("Could not connect to localhost");
   mysql_select_db("db") or die( "Could not connect to database");
?>

    <p class="scroll">
<?php
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM this ORDER BY name ASC");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<div style='margin: 0 auto;'>
                    <span style='display:inline-block; width:200px; text-align:left;'>" . ucwords($row['name']) . "</span>
                    <span style='display:inline-block; text-align:left;'>" . ucwords($row['number']) . "</span>
                </div>
                <br>";
   }
?>
   </p>
 </font>
</div>
```

[css]

```
.scroll 
{
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

How would I add the scrollbar to the right of the output and make it scrolldown to see all of the data displayed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this...

```
.scroll {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

This is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JtUz6/1/)

Comment: This put the scrollbar directly on TOP of the information not on the side so the information is not scrollable..

Comment: This coding is working. If this is not your expecting result, please explain it in details.

Comment: Then add `.scroll` class to `div` in while loop not in `p` tag

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
.scroll {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

You don't want `overflow: scroll;` unless you also want a horizontal scrollbar.  You also need to give it a width and height.

Comment: This put the scrollbar directly on TOP of the information not on the side so the information is not scrollable..